# Meaning of parameters of control_msgs/JointControllerState.msg

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.

Can everyone help me explain the meaning of following parameters in `JointControllerState` message?

```
float64 set_point
float64 process_value
float64 process_value_dot
float64 error
float64 time_step
float64 command
```

Thanks a lot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/323036/meaning-of-parameters-of-control_msgs/jointcontrollerstate.msg/) by [smilels](https://answers.ros.org/users/41449/smilels/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-05-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As the name implies (`JointControllerState`) this message is/may be used to publish the (internal) *state* of a joint (pid) controller.

As to the fields:

> ```
> float64 set_point
> ```

the current set point (ie: desired state).

> ```
> float64 process_value
> ```

the current value of the process (ie: latest sensor measurement on the controlled value).

> ```
> float64 process_value_dot
> ```

first time-derivative of the process value.

> ```
> float64 error
> ```

Essentially `process_value - set_point` (for a regular PID implementation).

> ```
> float64 time_step
> ```

time between two consecutive updates/execution of the control law (ie: delta-t).

> ```
> float64 command
> ```

current output of the controller.

As an example: see the [JointVelocityController](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_controllers/blob/b112b1cb20b3bc3d9be604136204fcba959e49a3/effort_controllers/src/joint_velocity_controller.cpp#L148-L164) in `ros_control`.

Finally: it might be nice to contribute some comments to the message definition file in [ros-controls/control_msgs](https://github.com/ros-controls/control_msgs) if you now understand what the purpose of these fields is.

That would help future readers and users of the message avoid questions such as the one you posted.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-05-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [smilels](https://answers.ros.org/users/41449/smilels/) on 2019-05-13**:
Thank you. Your answer is pretty clear. I have applied a pull request for ros-controls/control_msgs.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-05-14**:
re: PR: very nice. Thank you for that.